# Which option is more efficient (database queries using PDO)

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm building a class to deal with database operations and I decided to use PDO.

At first I decided to use static methods to simplify the calls, since the attributes don't change and the methods are independent, so I don't need to save the reference of the object. However, with this solution I would have to instanciate a new PDO object for every call of some method of such class, connect to the database, then prepare thge query and execute.

Bellow is an example of the base of a insert mnethod for this class:

```
public static function insert($table, $columns, $values){
    $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.self::$db.'; host='.self::$host.'; charset=utf8', self::$login, self::$pass);

    ... create the sql query and the associative array of values

    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($array_aux);
}
```

So I'm wondering if instanciating the PDO object in every call is too inefficient and if it's best if I store the PDO reference and so, don't use static methods.

ps: I know that some people hate static methods, since they are hard to unit test, but in some cases they are pretty handy.

Comment: There's also static variables, you could use one to store pdo connection

Comment: Ok, but I'm using static methods so I don't have to store the objects reference of my class that handles db operations. Even if I use a static variable to store the pdo connection, I would not be able to use it after, since the object's reference would be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an example of @nikita2206's suggestion:

```
private $pdo = null;
private static function getDB(){
    if(is_null(self::$pdo)) self::$pdo = new PDO(...);
    return self::$pdo;
}
public static function insert($table, $columns, $values){
     $dbConnection  = self::getDB();
     ....
}
```

Mind you: your code, using static methods & variables like this becomes wholly untestable with mock-pdo objects... They're not that much better then global variables at this point, Dependancy Injection would be preferred.

Comment: Ok, but in case I use dependancy injection I think it wouldn't be possible or at least wouldn't be the better option using static method, right?

Comment: Erm... I'm not realy understanding the question here... Dependancy Injection is of course possible (and be better), but will most likely require a (big) design change. This works, and millions of applications work this way, so there's no problem in using it. I just wanted to warn you about the drawbacks.

Comment: Srry, I meant that by using dependency injection I would have to create a pdo objet outside my class and use it when calling methods like insert, right? So my question was, if I am to keep an object's reference, wouldn't be better to giving up on static methods?

Comment: The db-connection lives as long as your static interface you have now, so an instance which is instantiated with the database instance in its constructor would not need the db passed in it's instance methods, as it's already a property. You inject that instance containing the db into other objects which would need to call the `insert()` method.